# RESTDataSource - How to know if response comes from get request or cache

Tags: express, apollo, apollo-server, apollo-datasource-rest

I need to get some data from a REST API in my GraphQL API. For that I'm extending `RESTDataSource` from `apollo-datasource-rest`.

From what I understood, RESTDataSource caches automatically requests but I'd like to verify if it is indeed cached. Is there a way to know if my request is getting its data from the cache or if it's hitting the REST API?

I noticed that the first request takes some time, but the following ones are way faster and also, the `didReceiveResponse` method is not called everytime I make a query. Is it because the data is loaded from the cache?

I'm using apollo-server-express.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can time the requests like following:

```
console.time('restdatasource get req') 
this.get(url)
console.timeEnd('restdatasource get req')
```

Now, if the time is under 100-150 milliseconds, that should be a request coming from the cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor the console, under the network tab. You will be able to see what endpoints the application is calling. If it uses cached data, there will be no new request to your endpoint logged

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to verify this locally, one good option is to setup a local proxy so that you can see all the network calls being made. (no network call meaning the call was read from cache) Then you can simply configure your app using this [apollo documentation](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/proxy-configuration/) to forward all outgoing calls through a proxy like [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/).